# Creating customer records and saving cards during Stripe checkout?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, stripe

My client is looking to, on occasion, assign a recurring Stripe plan to a one-time donor (most donations on this site are one-time). The best way to do this would be to create a customer in Stripe (and save the card token for that customer) on every transaction, so that it would  be a quick and easy process for them to find the customer and assign them a plan without needing to collect any further information from them.

Currently the Stripe plugin doesn't save anything, it simply creates a simple one-time charge.

Is it possible to use existing actions in the Stripe gateway for Commerce 2 to create customers w/ saved sources during checkout?